# Что такое шаблонизаторы для node.js и какая обласить их применения?

Tags: node.js, шаблоны

Здравствуйте. Не раз слышал об шаблонизаторах для node.js, но в интернете так и не нашел конкретного описания что это и как оно применяется. Хотел бы услышать от вас которую информацию о них. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Шаблонизатор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) - это [модуль](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/using-template-engines.html), позволяющий использовать упрощенный и более мощный синтаксис для написания html. Шаблонизатор отделяет представление данных от исполняемого кода, даёт возможность разделять шаблоны на блоки, переиспользовать их несколько раз, выделять макросы, наследовать шаблоны ит.д., как результат - процесс верстки ускоряется, код становится короче.
Вот некоторые из них

- [Pug (бывший jade)](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) - мой выбор
- [Twig](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js) можно использовать и на фронтедне
- [Ejs](https://github.com/tj/ejs)
- [Aptl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/atpl)
- [Over 9000](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=template)!

Кроме того, в новых версиях nodejs поддерживаются [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), которые можно использовать для простой шаблонизации

Comment: а angular.js считается шаблонизатором?

Comment: в angular встроен свой шаблонизатор, но angular это фреймворк